# least sum of vertical line in 2d array

Tags: c#, recursion, sum

I have a 2D array I have the

number of rows = H
number of columns = W
the 2d array itself = arr
they are all integers

I am tasked to return the lowest sum of the vertical line starts with each point at first row

input

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

output 12

I thought about a way to solve this by using recursion but i don't get right results.

the function takes the array, the position i want to calculate minimum sum at (should be on the first-row coz it's a line) number of columns and rows and res is to return the sum res is initialized in the main function by arr at row x and column y

I am sure about the idea but the way I am summing is probably wrong

```
static int Summ(int [,]arr,int x,int y,int W,int H,int res)
    {
        if (x == H - 1)
            res += arr[x, y];
        else
            if (y == 0)
                res += Math.Min(Summ(arr, x + 1, y, W, H, res), Summ(arr, x + 1, y + 1, W, H, res));
            else if (y== W-1)
                res += Math.Min(Summ(arr, x + 1, y, W, H, res), Summ(arr, x + 1, y - 1, W, H, res));
            else 
                res+= res += Math.Min(Math.Min(Summ(arr, x + 1, y, W, H, res), Summ(arr, x + 1, y + 1, W, H, res)),Summ(arr,x+1,y-1,W,H,res));
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: "_lowest sum of the vertical line starts with each point at first row_", that make no sense. Mind creating a small grid and drawing those line with color? Or giging the index of every point of those line for a simple grid.

Comment: If I understand correctly your question:

You want to built a tree starting from {0,0}. 
Where all child node of a node {x,y} are {{x+1, y-1},{x+1,y},{x+1,y+1}}.

For a 3x3 the final tree will look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVlw9.png

Comment: First try to achieve this path, then do the sum , and do mni only on the resulting sum at the end of the tree. Any minimim befor may end up in you going the wrong path.

Comment: i couldn't post this question through stack overflow always get error when putting a code although stack exchange has same constraints when putting  a code but i was able to publish my question through there can't edit from it though and if choose edit here it won't let me save changes even tho i didn't really change anything so sorry for that  

as for thee question i solved it using recursion did the tree and analysis and sent it to the TA now i need to convert it to dynamic probably bottom-up i did the tree as u described at each then did the same at arr[0,0] until [0,Width]

Comment: sorry because the question is not clear but because of the virus i can't go to college to get support and it's hard to write how i am thinking about the sol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iterative solution may be simpler:

```
static int MinSum(int [,]arr)
{
    int min = Int32.MaxValue;

    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); ++j) 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); ++i)
        {
            sum += arr[i, j];
        }
        min = Math.min(min, sum);
    }

    return min;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Given the clarification in [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505580/least-sum-of-vertical-line-in-2d-array/65505674?noredirect=1#comment115814440_65505674), this solution is not correct.
Instead, you could iterate over the rows and sum the minimal value in each row:

```
static int MinSum(int [,]arr)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; j < arr.GetLength(0); ++i) 
    {
        int minCol = arr[i, 0];
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.GetLength(1); +_j)
        {
            minCoal = Math.min(minCol, arr[i, j]);
        }
        min += minCol;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: this will calculate the sum of each column but i am not doing that 
4 9 5
6 2 3
7 1 8
the output should be 4+2+1
for every point, I can go down or down-left if available or downright if available to try all possible solutions

Comment: @user13674310, clarification goes into the question via the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65505580/edit) button. Clarification that invalidate an answer must be avoided. That why writing a question you get prompt 3 time with [ask] and [mre]

Comment: @user13674310 I misunderstood the question then. See my edited answer.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVlw9.png 
thanks to Drag and Drop this clarify my question exactly what i do in this pic at arr[0,0]
i do it at arr[0,1] untill arr[0,Width-1) so i have the minimum sum of each node at first row and it's children in this tree u can clearly see the overlapping so i will need to convert it to dynamic programming 

the edited code gets the minimum in each row and sum them

Comment: i researched a bit and found that this is called content-aware image resize using minimum seam carving it does the same i am trying to do but both horizontally and vertically